# Linked List not retaining values across recursive function calls?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to implement a linked list that would store a memory address when encountering call/return assembly instructions. This works recursively by parsing each line of the assembly and only breaking out of the function when encountering either a call or return instruction. So far this works for call instructions, meaning that the return address is saved a node in a linked list, but when trying to retrieve this value during a return instruction the data has gone missing (meaning that the linked list is now empty). Here is what I am working with:

```
struct ret_addr {
    int address;
    struct ret_addr *nxt;
};

struct ret_addr *ret_data(cs_insn *insn, struct ret_addr **head) {
    struct ret_addr *r = malloc(sizeof(*r));
    r->address = insn->address + insn->size;
    r->nxt = (*head);
    (*head) = r;
    return r;
}

struct bb_data *disassemble_function_cfg(int startAddr, unsigned char *bytes, int end_section) {
    csh handle;
    cs_insn *insn;
    cs_detail *detail;
    cs_x86 *x86;
    size_t count;
    int stop_disasm = 0;
    struct bb_data *edges = NULL;
    struct ret_addr *ret_edge = NULL;

    count = cs_disasm(handle, bytes, end_section, startAddr, 1, &insn);

    detail = insn->detail;
    for(int n = 0; n < detail->groups_count; n++) {

        //break when encountering a call instruction
        if(detail->groups[n] == X86_GRP_CALL) {
            stop_disasm = 1;
            vector_new(edges);
            edges = call_insn(handle, x86, insn, vector_back(edges));
            ret_edge = ret_data(insn, &ret_edge);
        }

        //break when encountering a return instruction
        else if(detail->groups[n] == X86_GRP_RET) {
            stop_disasm = 1;
            vector_new(edges);
            edges = ret_insn(insn, edges, &ret_edge);
        }

    }

    if(!stop_disasm) {
        disassemble_function_cfg(insn->address + insn->size, bytes + insn->size, end_section);
    }
    else {
        return edges;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you create a new list every time in `disassemble_function_cfg`. How would the list be preserved if it isn't passed into the function?

Comment: `vector_new(edges);
            edges = ret_insn(insn, edges, &ret_edge);` This looks like a leak, edges is only a pointer. (but we don't know what vector_new() is, of course)

Comment: `vector_new` is a macro which creates an instances of a struct with malloc and realloc calls. sorry i should have included that within the original post

Answer (score 1):

You don't preserve your list between recursive calls. What you might want to do:

```
struct bb_data *disassemble_function_cfg(struct ret_addr **ret_edge, int startAddr, unsigned char *bytes, int end_section)
{
   ...
   if(*ret_edge == NULL) *ret_edge = ret_data(insn, ret_edge);
   ...
}
```

Comment: i tried to implement this but got the warning: `passing argument of 2 of ret_data from incompatible pointer type`